# Right logic to fetch any object or array from JSON

Tags: java, json

Whenever it comes as fetch data from a particular JSON array of object, I am not able to do a different kind of JSON response changes the array and object.

Not sure what kind of logic or approach I should have to handle a different kind of responses and to fetch data from them

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "message": "OK",
    "data": {
        "abc": [
            {
                "log_id": "157988454",
                "serial": 1
            }
        ],
        "pagination": {
            "now": 1,
            "next": false,
            "page": 1,
            "limit": 25,
            "limitstart": 0,
            "total": 1,
            "extra": null
        }
    }
}
```

Now as my per my thinking, my code should be able to fetch any data from the above response without changing my code for each block.

Comment: In Java, there a numerous frameworks able to read JSON into a own representation of objects: javax.json.Json, Jackson, ...

Comment: Deep first search?\

Comment: can anyone explain with one example?

Comment: You can use google now since you got terms.

Comment: I was expecting an example.